# how to create a global variable in a Eclipse PDT application?

Tags: java, eclipse, global-variables

I have an Eclipse PDT applicaction and I want/need to use a global variable that can be retrieved everywhere in the app.

I need a sort of "last_client" o "last invice" to let the application be more "agile" when the user goes from one screen to another.
It's difficult to explain without an example, but basically I need a global variable so when teh application creates a combo for letting the user select an entities , the combo will be default to that global variable if is set.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to that class.that variable.  Assuming the class is called "invoice" and the variable is called "user" it would look like:

```
lastUser = invoice.user;
```

You'd need to make the variable public to access it from a different class.  If you want it to be private (and you should!) You'll need to create a getter method for it. Like:

```
public String returnUser()
{
return user;
}
```

And you'd call it from the other class like:

```
lastUser = invoice.returnUser;
```

Hope that's useful!

Comment: close .. what I need is to store in the application the "lastUser" variable. I created a property in Activator class, and create getters and Setter, but I don't know if is the right way